# Where am I going wrong in Codeigniter's Static Pages Tutorial?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm follwing the tutorial on https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/tutorial/static_pages.html for learning the system. When it says to view the pages, I get a HTTP 500 error.

Codeignitor was installed correctly and the default welcome page pulled up. I just can't figure out where I'm going wrong on this.

```
class Pages extends CI_Controller {

public function view($page = 'home')
{

    if ( ! file_exists( APPATH . 'views/pages/' . $page . '.php'))
    {
        // Whoops, we don't have a page for that!
        show_404();
    }

    $data['title'] = ucfirst($page); // Capitalize the first letter

    $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
    $this->load->view('pages/'.$page, $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);

}
```

Comment: Is that all your code? I think it's missing a closing brace.

Comment: That was it.... sometimes it's the simplest solutions

Answer (score 0):

It's `APPPATH` instead of `APPATH`.

Answer (score 0):

Like already answered, it's `APPPATH`.

APPPATH is a constant that contains a string which if called from a controller returns "application/"

try this:

```
public function view($page = 'home')
{

    if ( ! file_exists( APPPATH . "views/pages/{$page}.php"))
    {
        // Whoops, we don't have a page for that!
        show_404();

    } else {

    $data['title'] = ucfirst($page); // Capitalize the first letter

    $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
    $this->load->view("pages/{$page}", $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);

    }
}
```